# Is m() in for(Obj o: m()) run once or multiple times?

Tags: java

In the following, is `m()` run once or multiple times?

```
for(Obj o: m()) { ... }
```

Comment: I am concerned that such a test will not reflect the semantics; that the observable behaviour on my machine is bound to the environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`m()` is evaluated once at the start of the loop. If `m()` is an `Iterable<Obj>`, it is used to produce an iterator that produces the values for the loop. That iterator is only created once.

Comment: If `m()` *returns* an *`Iterable`* you mean. Otherwise it won't compile.

Comment: @EJP Yes, that would be more accurate. I'll edit my answer. Thanks